# Transaction not being mined within 750 seconds

Tags: transactions, mining, etherscan, pending-transactions, error

On the main net, after getting the error from the title, by making sure it's not in pending pool, how long should I wait until I can safely retry a transaction?

Thanks

Comment: add more informationen please, what are you using web3j , web3js , normal transaction, how much gas....

Comment: This is a general question, shouldn't require such information. But if you think it helps, I am using web3js, ERC20 transfer, gas price obtained from a gas tracker API + 10%. Web3js' `sendSignedTransaction` fails after 12 minutes with this error and I want to make sure I am not duplicating the transaction. How long should I wait for?

Comment: okay, but the transaction will not be duplicated. I think if you send the transaction again without any change (the same gas and nonce) then the "new" transaction will be rejected as long the "old" tx exists in the pool or got already mined. However, if you increase the gas price then it will be replaced by the new transaction. I think these 12 minutes in web3js can be changed.

Comment: I agree, thanks. But the thing is I send lots of transactions, without trying to replace any of them. If they fail with this error, I want to know how long I need to wait until is safe to re-send it

Comment: Okay it seems no one could give an answer, I will upvote. Anyway I think it depends on the configuration of the miners and if the network is overloaded

Comment: get the gas fee from the ethergas station and set it programtically it will solve your problem